# MySQL Subquery for max employee hours

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I've got a database table called "hours" which has the following fields:  `"employee_id" (INT), "time_on" (DATETIME), and "time_off" (DATETIME)`. I want to see which employee logged the most hours in a month.

I'm thinking I need a Subquery but I'm not very good with MySQL, and I cannot wrap my head around the query I need.  I want to select all rows from this month with:

```
"... MONTH(time_on) = ".$this_month_object->format('m')."... "
```

Then with those rows, I want to select the "employee_id" field with the highest seconds worked using something like:

```
SUM(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(time_off, time_on)))
```

The last few hours have proved fruitless and I need some fresh ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT employee_id, SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_off, time_on)) AS diff
FROM tbl
WHERE YEAR(time_on) = 2013
    AND MONTH(time_on) = 3
GROUP BY employee_id
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b5ae/5)

Comment: Never used GROUP BY before, therefore didn't know it to be a tool.  Thanks @FreshPrinceOfSO